# Setting Text in Edit Text takes time after retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android project, and I am using Firebase Realtime Database to store my data.

Problem - EditTexts fields in my activity gets displayed first and then there's a time gap of around 5 seconds when my EditTexts is populated with the data which I am reading from the database.

Here's the code -

```
private void updatePersonalInfo() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("resumeDataOfUser").child(userPhoneNumber).child("Personal Info");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
               map.put(snapshot.getKey().toString(),snapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            if(!map.containsKey("linkedInUserName")){
                for( HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet() ){
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("pincode")) mAddressPinCode.getEditText().setText(entry.getValue());
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("otherPhone")) mOtherPhoneNumber.getEditText().setText(entry.getValue());
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("city")) mAddressCity.getEditText().setText(entry.getValue());
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("name")) mFullName.getEditText().setText(entry.getValue());
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("state")) mAddressState.setText(entry.getValue());
                    if(entry.getKey().equals("email")) mEmail.getEditText().setText(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

This is the structure of database -

[image: structure]

Is there any way by which I can speed up this process, because I don't think my approach of setting data to the corresponding EditTexts is the best and the fastest one. Any help would be appreciated.

I am displaying data like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the users Internet bandwidth. 
Use a progress circle dialog to show some interactive UI to the user.

Comment: I don't think this is an approach I want to go with.This will make user interaction with my application very poor.

Comment: Then u can provide strong internet connection to your users to avoid that lag!

Comment: I researched a lot to solve that issue, but couldn't. The only logical explanation of problem was bad Internet connectivity. So now I am using a progress bar till the data is loaded and displayed on UI

Comment: Thats nice! :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know why you put the values and keys in a `map`, and then loop through them while you can easily extract the values using `dataSnapshot` directly:**

```
private void updatePersonalInfo() {
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("resumeDataOfUser").child(userPhoneNumber).child("Personal Info");


reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    //get values 
    String pinCode = dataSnapshot.child("pincode").getValue(String.class);
    String otherPhone = dataSnapshot.child("otherPhone").getValue(String.class);
    String city = dataSnapshot.child("city").getValue(String.class);
    String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
    String state = dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue(String.class);
    String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);

    //set the values
    mAddressPinCode.getEditText().setText(pinCode);
    mOtherPhoneNumber.getEditText().setText(otherPhone);
    mAddressCity.getEditText().setText(city);
    mFullName.getEditText().setText(name);
    mAddressState.getEditText().setText(state);
    mEmail.getEditText().setText(email);




    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
    });
 }
```

Comment: The problem still persist

Comment: Okay look before you set the values to editext, log the values to the console and see how long do they take to print to console.

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on the user's internet speed. You need to display a progress dialog UI to alert the user to please wait while the data loads from firebase.

[Progress dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mCgg.png)